# Random quote machine or tweet current quote doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

jQuery on click function to tweet current quote doesn't want to work. What is wrong here. I have to build random quote machine and tweet current quote. I've managed to do JSON API but cannot figure out how to tweet current quote. Please help.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class = "well">


<div class="row">

<h2 class="text text-center"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"> </i> Hey, what when and why there is no and yes?</h2>


<p class="author">-Alina Khachatrian</p>



<div class="buttons">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <a id="tweet-quote" title="Tweet current quote" target="_blank" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
      </a> 
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6">
   <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default btn-transparent" id ="getNewQuote" title="Get a new quote">New Quote</button>
 </div>
</div>
<footer class="text-center">
<hr>
<p>Written and coded by <a href="https://github.com/edkiljak">Edgar Kiljak</a>.</p>
</footer>  
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").on("click", function(){
        $.getJSON("http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/quotes.json", function (json) {

  var html = "";
  var len = json.length;
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
  var val = json[index];

  html += "<div class = 'newQuote'>";

  html += "<h3>'" + val.quote + "'</h3>";


  html += "</div>";
  $(".author").text(val.author);

  $(".text").html(html);

    $('#tweet-quote').on("click",function(){
       window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+
      $(val.quote).text() +"&via=your-app-name&original_referer=your-url");
     });

   });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem I had was that I couldn't even see the link to Tweet Current Quote. I had to add the text in the anchor:

```
  <a id="tweet-quote" title="Tweet current quote" target="_blank" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
  TWEET CURRENT QUOTE
  </a>
```

Second: it was popping up the new Twitter window, but not filling the text. In your onclick code, the `$(val.quote).text()` was unnecessary - just use `val.quote`

Third: you'll see that in addition to opening the new Twitter window, it is opening another occurrence of your own page. This has to do with how you have the `tweet-quote` anchor defined in your html, but the easiest way to stop it is to add return false in your onclick so that the target in the anchor doesn't fire:

```
$('#tweet-quote').on("click",function(){
   window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+
  val.quote +"&via=your-app-name&original_referer=your-url");return false;
 });
```

Fourth: if you load a second 'New Quote', and then click the 'Tweet This Quote', you'll see that it opens **two** new windows -- it is tweeting both the old and the new quotes. This is because the `on("click")` is cumulative. You should clear out any existing function before setting the new one:

```
$('#tweet-quote').unbind("click");
$('#tweet-quote').on("click",function(){
   window.open ...
```

Fifth: Usually when you post a question here, "doesn't work" is not a sufficient explanation. You should explain what's not working, or what is working differently than you want it to. Error messages if there are any. What you saw in the console logs. Some people get real sticky about that. And some people will probably get sticky about me doing your homework for you. Good luck though!

Comment: Thank you so much Alan. I'm also trying to replace 
  val.quote +"&via=your-app-name&original_referer=your-url" with #myfavoritequote after the quote. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Okay, you should have tried:  `val.quote + "#myfavoritequote" + "&via..` and seen that when the twitter page come up, the hashtag was missing. That's because # is a special character that needs to be encapsulated. `val.quote + encodeURIComponent('#myfavoritequote') + "&via=` will work. Actually you may see that some of the quotes from the robot contain special characters that cause the tweet to be cut off on the twitter page. You can fix that with `encodeURIComponent(val.quote)`.

Comment: Thanks indeed! Much appreciated!